# Problems with Redmine 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 ruby(1.8.24) on rails(3.2.11) couldn't be started

Tags: apache2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, ubuntu-10.04, passenger

Hi I face the following problem upgrading to Redmine 2.2.1 from 1.2.2 on Ubuntu 10.04LTS:
Initial hiccups i could resolve but now opening the redmine webpage i get an error.

I followed the step in http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade
and upgraded the required stuffs.

Do i have some compatibility issue with rails and passenger or some configuration is apache?
I am unable to figure. Kindly help me in figuring out the issue.

Thanks in advance,
Ghosh.

**Webpage error:**

```
A source file that the application requires, is missing.
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
no such file to load -- dispatcher
Exception class:
LoadError
Application root:
/usr/share/redmine
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `require'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `require'
2   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 236 in `load_dependency'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb 251 in `require'
4   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    308 in `preload_application'
5   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    248 in `initialize_server'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb    255 in `report_app_init_status'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    233 in `initialize_server'
8   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  194 in `start_synchronously'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  163 in `start'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb    209 in `start'
11  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    262 in `spawn_rails_application'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   126 in `lookup_or_add'
13  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    256 in `spawn_rails_application'
14  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   80  in `synchronize'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb   79  in `synchronize'
16  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    255 in `spawn_rails_application'
17  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    154 in `spawn_application'
18  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb    287 in `handle_spawn_application'
19  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  352 in `__send__'
20  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  352 in `main_loop'
21  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb  196 in `start_synchronously'
22  /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server   61
```

**My Redmine related stuffs are configured as below:**

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.2.1.stable
  Ruby version                             1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.11
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         MySQL
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed

Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.11)
  * actionpack (3.2.11)
  * activemodel (3.2.11)
  * activerecord (3.2.11)
  * activeresource (3.2.11)
  * activesupport (3.2.11)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.2.3)
  * coderay (1.0.8)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * fastercsv (1.5.5)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.1)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.3)
  * json (1.7.6)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.19)
  * multi_json (1.5.0)
  * mysql (2.8.1)
  * net-ldap (0.3.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.4)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-openid (1.3.1)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (3.2.11)
  * railties (3.2.11)
  * rake (10.0.3)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * ruby-openid (2.1.8)
  * sprockets (2.2.2)
  * thor (0.16.0)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.12)
  * tzinfo (0.3.35)

root@ubuntu:/usr/share/redmine# gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.11, 2.3.11)
actionpack (3.2.11, 2.3.11)
activemodel (3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.11, 2.3.11)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
activeresource (3.2.11, 2.3.11)
activesupport (3.2.11, 2.3.11)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.2.3)
coderay (1.0.8)
daemon_controller (1.1.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.7.6)
mail (2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
mocha (0.12.3)
multi_json (1.5.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
passenger (3.0.19)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4, 1.1.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.3.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.11)
railties (3.2.11)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
rubygems-update (1.8.24)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
```

Comment: I assume you've run the "bundle install" command?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in another forum, and I'd like to post the resolution here in case anyone else needs it...

I updated passenger:

gem update passenger

Then:

passenger-install-apache2-module

Then modify apache2.conf file to use the new passenger version. The above installer tells you what needs to be modified in your environment.

Then restart apache and voila!

Hope this helps.